# Search Form Same Line

Tags: css, html, search, button

I cannot seem to make the search button and input box be aligned on the same line...currently the textbox is above the search button...any tips?

```
<!-- Search Bar -->
<div class="headline headline-md"><h2>Search</h2></div>
<div class="input-group margin-bottom-40">
<form method="get" action="@Url.ArticulateSearchUrl(Model)">
    <input type="text" name="term" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
    <span class="input-group-btn"><button type="submit" class="btn-u"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button></span>
</form>
</div>
<!-- End Search Bar -->
```

Comment: Add the CSS you've tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. This did the trick:

```
<!-- Search Bar -->
<div class="headline headline-md"><h2>Search</h2></div>
<div class="input-group margin-bottom-40">
<form class="input-group" method="get" action="@Url.ArticulateSearchUrl(Model)">
    <div class="input-group-btn">
        <input type="text" name="term" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
        <span><button type="submit" class="btn-u"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button></span>
    </div>
</form>
</div>
<!-- End Search Bar -->
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `<div>`s the `<h2>` and the `<form>` are `display:block` and fill the width of their container

You can convert your HTML to

```
<div class="headline headline-md"><h2>Search</h2></div>
<form method="get" action="@Url.ArticulateSearchUrl(Model)">
    <input type="text" name="term" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
    <span class="input-group-btn"><button type="submit" class="btn-u"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button></span>
</form>
```

and add this CSS

```
.headline-md,h2,form{
   display:inline-block;
}

.headline-md{
width:80px;
margin-right:15px;
}
```

I added `!important` to force the new CSS rules. I added a code snippet to demonstrate the code.

```css
    .headline-md,h2,form{
       display:inline-block !important;
    }

    .headline-md{
    width:80px !important;
    margin-right:15px !important;
    }
```

```html
<div class="headline headline-md"><h2>Search</h2></div>
    <form method="get" action="@Url.ArticulateSearchUrl(Model)">
        <input type="text" name="term" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
        <span class="input-group-btn"><button type="submit" class="btn-u"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button></span>
    </form>
```

Comment: Thanks, it's strange because it still doesn't work on my end...? It just made the input textbox wider...

Comment: @Bobi Can you post your full code including CSS? This way we may be able to spot what's wrong with your code. Also can you please upvote the answer if you believe it's correct?

Comment: I will let you know when I upload the file to the server. There are a tonne of css and js files.